# Get the week numbers between two dates with python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, rrule

I'd like to find the most pythonic way to output a list of the week numbers between two dates.

For example:

**input**

```
start = datetime.date(2011, 12, 25) 
end = datetime.date(2012, 1, 21)
```

**output**

```
find_weeks(start, end)
>> [201152, 201201, 201202, 201203]
```

I've been struggling using the datetime library with little success

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something in the lines of (**update:** removed less-readable option)

```
import datetime

def find_weeks(start,end):
    l = []
    for i in range((end-start).days + 1):
        d = (start+datetime.timedelta(days=i)).isocalendar()[:2] # e.g. (2011, 52)
        yearweek = '{}{:02}'.format(*d) # e.g. "201152"
        l.append(yearweek)
    return sorted(set(l))

start = datetime.date(2011, 12, 25) 
end = datetime.date(2012, 1, 21)

print(find_weeks(start,end)[1:]) # [1:] to exclude first week.
```

Returns

```
['201152', '201201', '201202', '201203']
```

To include the first week (201151) simply remove `[1:]` after function call

Comment: Interesting approach! Seems like the "more Pythonic" version that OP was asking for, +1

Comment: @asongtoruin Thanks. You also had something nice going but I think it is more safe to just use all the days and set().

Comment: Thanks both. Possibly even more pythonic would be to turn it into a one-liner list comprehension. Harder to understand what's going on though.

Comment: @Ludo I had a listcomprehension in the beginning, but when it can't fit one line I don't think it is pythonic anymore (readability first!). In light of that I separated way the format line.

Comment: @Ludo being "Pythonic" isn't necessarily the be-all and end-all. Readability is important too - I think this answer has a good mix of being concise but very understandable.

Answer (score 3):

`.isocalendar()` is your friend here - it returns a tuple of `(year, week of year, day of week)`. We use that to reset the start date to the start of th eweek, and then add on a week each time until we pass the end date:

```
import datetime


def find_weeks(start_date, end_date):
    subtract_days = start_date.isocalendar()[2] - 1
    current_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=7-subtract_days)
    weeks_between = []
    while current_date <= end_date:
        weeks_between.append(
            '{}{:02d}'.format(*current_date.isocalendar()[:2])
        )
        current_date += datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    return weeks_between

start = datetime.date(2011, 12, 25)
end = datetime.date(2012, 1, 21)

print(find_weeks(start, end))
```

This prints

```
['201152', '201201', '201202', '201203']
```

Answer (score 3):

Using  Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

dates=pd.date_range(start=start,end=end,freq='W')
date_index=dates.year.astype(str)+dates.weekofyear.astype(str).str.zfill(2)
date_index.tolist()
```

Comment: I like the pandas format solution for readability, but runs slower than the datetime solution:

datetime: 46.9 µs ± 442 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

pandas: 883 µs ± 30.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: I changed the format... but this solution still doesn't include the last week.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following easy-to-read solution:

```
import datetime

start = datetime.date(2011, 12, 25) 
end = datetime.date(2012, 1, 21)

def find_weeks(start, end):
    l = []
    while (start.isocalendar()[1] != end.isocalendar()[1]) or (start.year != end.year):
        l.append(start.isocalendar()[1] + 100*start.year)
        start += datetime.timedelta(7)
    l.append(start.isocalendar()[1] + 100*start.year)
    return (l[1:])


print(find_weeks(start, end))

>> [201252, 201201, 201202, 201203]
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the `arrow` style solution here (might need `pip install arrow`):

```py
import arrow

start = arrow.get('2011-12-25')
end = arrow.get('2012-01-21')
weeks = list(arrow.Arrow.span_range('week', start, end))
```

result looks like this:

```py
>> from pprint import pprint
>> pprint(weeks[1:])
[(<Arrow [2011-12-19T00:00:00+00:00]>,
  <Arrow [2011-12-25T23:59:59.999999+00:00]>),
 (<Arrow [2011-12-26T00:00:00+00:00]>,
  <Arrow [2012-01-01T23:59:59.999999+00:00]>),
 (<Arrow [2012-01-02T00:00:00+00:00]>,
  <Arrow [2012-01-08T23:59:59.999999+00:00]>),
 (<Arrow [2012-01-09T00:00:00+00:00]>,
  <Arrow [2012-01-15T23:59:59.999999+00:00]>),
 (<Arrow [2012-01-16T00:00:00+00:00]>,
  <Arrow [2012-01-22T23:59:59.999999+00:00]>)]
```

from there you can change the output to match the year and week number.